# search in codeigniter if my input data is match either not

Tags: codeigniter, search

i want to search in codeigniter if my input data is matched then shows result but couldn't match couldn't shows data..

Here is my model:

```
public function get_search(){
    $p_cat = $this->input->post('p_category');
    $p_place = $this->input->post('p_place');
    $p_price = $this->input->post('p_price');
    $search = $this->input->post('search');
    $this->db->like('p_category',$p_cat,$search);
    $this->db->or_like('p_place',$p_place,$search);
    $this->db->or_like('p_price',$p_price,$search);
    $query = $this->db->get('tbl_property');

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
         return $query->result_array();
    else
         return FALSE;
}
```

But this model result match or mismatch it shows any data...

Answer (score 0):

You have issue in your or_like method calling of query builder class. It should be like:

```
public function get_search(){

// Below three lines is not useful until you are using any other conditions to fetch data from DB
$p_cat = $this->input->post('p_category');
$p_place = $this->input->post('p_place');
$p_price = $this->input->post('p_price');

// I guess this string should be search in three columns
$search = $this->input->post('search');
$this->db->like('p_category',$search);
$this->db->or_like('p_place',$search);
$this->db->or_like('p_price',$search);
$query = $this->db->get('tbl_property');

if($query->num_rows() > 0)
     return $query->result_array();
else
     return FALSE;
}
```

Let me know if you still face any issue.

Comment: Can you please explain, what exactly you want to implement?